# P5.js how to do 8 directional lerp color/color change?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

A last issue i have in this code is that i am not sure how to create color change effect as 8 directional.
I can only map a mouseX to make it lerpColor horizontally or vertically .
But how do i make it work through moving both mouseX and mouseY?

I had it in shift_Color method within the class. I tried to state that within a certain dist(), lerpColor. But now it only showing black color rather than the changing color effect.

```js
let cubes = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  backCol = color(243, 243, 243);
  //background(backCol);

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      let xPos = map(i, 0, 9, 50, width - 50);
      let yPos = map(j, 0, 9, 50, height - 50);

      cubes.push(new Cubes(xPos, yPos));

    }
  }

}

function draw() {
  background(backCol);
  noFill();

  for (let a = 0; a < cubes.length; a++) {
    cubes[a].update();
  }
}

class Cubes {

  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = 30;
    this.stroke = 70;
    this.gap = 110
    this.shift1 = color(96);
    this.shift2 = color(244);
  }

  update() {
    this.shape();
    this.shift_Color();
  }
  
  shape() {
    push();
    stroke(this.stroke);
    //fill(this.shift1);
    this.shift_Color();
    translate(this.x - width / 2, this.y - height / 2, 0);
    this.magnetic()
    box(this.size);
    pop();
  }

  shift_Color() {
    let distance = dist(mouseX, mouseY, this.x, this.y);

    if (distance < this.gap) {
      this.shift1 = color(96);
      this.shift2 = color(244);
      this.shiftX = map(mouseX - width/2,this.gap,distance,0,1.0);
      this.change = lerpColor(this.shift1, this.shift2, this.shiftX);
      fill(this.change);
    } else {
      fill(this.shift1);
    }
  }

  magnetic() {
    let distance = dist(mouseX, mouseY, this.x, this.y);

    if (distance < this.gap) {
      this.attract = atan2(mouseY - this.y, mouseX - this.x);
      rotateX(this.attract);
      rotateY(this.attract);
    } else {
      rotateX(millis() / 1000);
      rotateY(millis() / 1000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to add additional information about 8 directional lerp color/color change? What exactly is your goal?

Comment: I am trying to make a color changing behaviour that makes the center of the mouse cusor to have color(244); and lerpColor to color(96); as the distance from the center of the cursor increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, there are two problems in your code.

The first is the fact that because you are trying to map the distance between mouse and the cube to number between 0 and 1, you should write `lerpColor(this.shift2, this.shift1, this.shiftX)` instead of `lerpColor(this.shift1, this.shift2, this.shiftX)`, since `this.shift2` is the lighter color and will be the inner color.

Another problem is when mapping the `change` variable, `change` should be calculated based on the distance between mouse and the cube (which is the `distance` variable), not `mouseX` or `mouseY`. Solution is to simply do `map(distance, 0, this.gap, 0, 1);`.

```js
let cubes = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  backCol = color(243, 243, 243);

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      let xPos = map(i, 0, 9, 50, width - 50);
      let yPos = map(j, 0, 9, 50, height - 50);

      cubes.push(new Cubes(xPos, yPos));

    }
  }

}

function draw() {
  background(backCol);
  noFill();

  for (let cube of cubes) {
    cube.update();
  }
}

class Cubes {

  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = 30;
    this.stroke = 70;
    this.gap = 110
    this.shift1 = color(96);
    this.shift2 = color(244);
  }

  update() {
    this.shape();
    this.shift_Color();
  }
  
  shape() {
    push();
    stroke(this.stroke);
    //fill(this.shift1);
    this.shift_Color();
    translate(this.x - width / 2, this.y - height / 2, 0);
    this.magnetic()
    box(this.size);
    pop();
  }

  shift_Color() {
    let distance = dist(mouseX, mouseY, this.x, this.y);

    if (distance < this.gap) {
      this.shiftX = map(distance, 0, this.gap, 0, 1);
      // this.shiftX = map(mouseX - width/2,this.gap,distance,0,1.0);
      this.change = lerpColor(this.shift2, this.shift1, this.shiftX);
      // this.change = lerpColor(this.shift1, this.shift2, this.shiftX);
      fill(this.change);
    } else {
      fill(this.shift1);
    }
  }

  magnetic() {
    let distance = dist(mouseX, mouseY, this.x, this.y);

    if (distance < this.gap) {
      this.attract = atan2(mouseY - this.y, mouseX - this.x);
      rotateX(this.attract);
      rotateY(this.attract);
    } else {
      rotateX(millis() / 1000);
      rotateY(millis() / 1000);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

I also modified some of your code. Like the line

```
this.shift1 = color(96);
this.shift2 = color(244);
```

which is not needed currently since neither of these variable changes during execution.

Comment: No problem. Good luck :)